jQueru Ui autocomlete remote with image
This jQuery Ui Autocomplete code with image works perfectly well, but the image appears on top of the text, I would like the image to appear on the left and text on the right, like the photo. Any suggestions?
$(function() {
var cache = {};
$("#myAutocomplete").autocomplete({
 minLength: 1,     
 source: function(request, response) {
  var term = request.term;
  if (term in cache) {
   response(cache[term]);
   return;
  }
  $.getJSON("services/test_ima_JAutocomplete1.asp", request, function(data, status, xhr) {
   status, xhr ) {
   cache[term] = data;
   response(data);
  });
 }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
     return $("<li></li>")
         .data("item.autocomplete", item)
         .append("<img src="+ item.image + ">" + "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
          .appendTo(ul);
  }
});


Fix with CSS or wrap it.
